# How to write all output from a shell script to a single new file

Tags: shell, file, append

Instead of putting `>>` at the end of each command such as:

```sh
date >> newfile
ls >> newfile
# etc.
```

How would I take the entire output of a script and put it into a file without the need for multiple appends, such as in the following code?

```sh
date
ls
echo $USER
# ">> new file"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exec` to redirect the output of the script (and hence any commands executed in the script):

```
#!/bin/sh

exec >> newfile  # Direct all output to newfile
date
ls
echo "$USER"
```

or you can redirect a block of commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

{
    date
    ls
    echo "$USER"
} >> newfile
```

You can also redirect to a file for some commands and restore for others:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 3>&1
exec > newfile
echo this output is written to newfile
exec >&3
echo this outupt goes to the original stdout
```

Comment: thank you! What if I want both - redirect to a file and show on stdout, without wrapping everything in `tee`?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654/272449

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this.

I was able to execute the script.sh file and simply redirect the output to a new file.

example:

./Script.sh > newfile.txt